# Flux of $v=(y_1e^{y_2}-e^{y_1},y_2e^{y_3}-e^{y_2},y_3e^{y_1}-e^{y_3})$ through a sphere

Tags: multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates, surface-integrals

> $v=(y_1e^{y_2}-e^{y_1},y_2e^{y_3}-e^{y_2},y_3e^{y_1}-e^{y_3})$
>
> $Y = (y_1^2+y_2^2+y_3^2=r^2, y_2>=0, y_3>=0)$
>
> Calculate flux of v through Y.

My first intuition was to use spherical coordinates so I set $\varphi(x)=(r\sin x_2\cos x_1, r\sin x_2 \sin x_1, r\cos x_2)$, with $x_1$ between $0$ and $\pi$ and $x_2$ between $0$ and $\pi/2$.

Then I wanted to use the Stokes-Ampère theorem, but I don't really know how to use it. I saw that div v = $0$ and found $\omega_v^2$. Then I found $\omega_u^1$ with $u=(0,y_3e^{y_1}-y_1e^{y_3},y_1y_2e^{y_3}-y_1e^{y_2})$.

But what now? How do I set the integral? In class we saw an example with polar coordinates and a simple u and it seemed easy with just one variable. But here I have spherical coordinates and the vector u is very confusing.

Could someone please explain how to use this theorem correctly and how do I integrate from here?

Comment: Since you found the divergence was zero, it would be much easier to close the surface with the two planes $y_2=0$ and $y_3=0$ then use divergence theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got the correction back and this is how we were supposed to do the exercise. Note that we only saw the divergence theorem this week, so we were supposed to solve this without using it.

So, as I wrote before, the divergence of $v$ is $0$.

Since the divergence of $v$ is $0$, there exists a $u$ such that rot$u=v$. And, by Stokes-Ampère, $\Phi=\int_{\partial Y}\omega_u^1$.
We're also going to be using Green-Riemann: $\int_{\varphi (K)}d\omega = \int_{\varphi (\partial K)}\omega$

So we have:

$\omega_v^2 = (y_3e^{y_1}-e^{y_3})dy_1\wedge dy_2 - (y_2e^{y_3}-e^{y_2})dy_1\wedge dy_3+(y_1e^{y_2}-e^{y_1})dy_2\wedge dy_3$ = $d(y_3e^{y_1}dy_2)+d(y_1e^{y_2}dy_3)+d(y_2e^{y_3}dy_1)$

And so $\omega_u^1=y_2e^{y_3}dy_1+y_3e^{y_1}dy_2+y_1e^{y_2}dy_3$

We need to calculate $\Phi=\int_{\partial Y}\omega_u^1$.

How do we parametrise $\partial Y$?

$\gamma_1 = r(-\cos t, \sin t,0)$, $\gamma_2 = r(\cos t, 0, \sin t)$, $t=(0,\pi)$

And so:

$\int_{\partial Y}\omega_u^1$ = $\int_{\gamma_1}\omega_u^1 + \int_{\gamma_2}\omega_u^1$=$r^2\int_0^{\pi}((\sin t) e^0 (\sin t) +0 +0)dt+r^2\int_0^{\pi}(0+0+(\cos t) e^0 (\cos t) dt$ = $r^2\int_0^{\pi}(\cos^2 t +\sin^2 t)dt = \pi r^2$

Answer (score 1):

$\vec F =(xe^y - e^x, ye^z - e^y, z e^x - e^z)$

Given surface is $S: x^2+y^2+z^2 = r^2; \ y, z \geq 0$

We can apply divergence theorem by closing the surface with semi-disks in plane $z = 0$ and $y = 0$.

$\nabla \cdot \vec F = e^y - e^x + e^z - e^y + e^x - e^z = 0$

As the divergence of the vector field is zero, its surface integral over closed surface is zero. Now we find the flux through semi-disks at $y = 0$ and at $z=0$ and subtract from the total flux which is zero. That would give us the flux through surface $S$.

For disk at $y = 0$, outward normal vector is $(0, -1, 0)$ and we can parametrize the surface as $(\rho \cos \theta, 0, \rho\sin \theta), 0 \leq \rho \leq r, 0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$.

For disk at $z = 0$, outward normal vector is $(0, 0, -1)$ and we can parametrize the surface as $(\rho \cos \theta, \rho\sin \theta, 0), 0 \leq \rho \leq r, 0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$.

It is easy to see that the total outward flux through both semi-disks is equal to the area of a circle of radius $r$.

Can you take it from here, fill in all the details and complete the working?

Comment: uhhh... i don't understand anything, sorry... why is the surface integral over the closed surface 0? and how did you get the normal vector and the parametrisation?

Comment: Before I explain, have you been taught divergence theorem yet?

Comment: we saw the stokes-ampère theorem that says that the flux is equal to the integral of $\omega_u^1$

Comment: What we are applying here is divergence theorem (or Gauss's theorem) which states that the flux of a vector field through a closed surface is equal to the volume integral of its divergence. Divergence of a vector field is calculated using $\nabla \cdot \vec F$. Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem

Comment: When you take partial derivative of $y_1$ component wrt $y_1$, of $y_2$ component wrt $y_2$ and same for $y_3$ and add, it is zero for the given vector field which means its divergence is zero.

Comment: Also wanted to mention that the theorem that you are talking about is applicable if you were finding flux of the curl of a vector field (curl of magnetic field in case of Ampere's law) and you wanted to translate it to the line integral of the magnetic field over the boundary curve of the surface.

Comment: so it turns out we didn't see the divergence theorem. we saw it for the first time in class today. i'll post the way we were supposed to do it when i get the correction back.

Comment: Ok let me know when you do.

Comment: another question: how did you find the outward normal vector?

Comment: For the closed surface it is volume integral so by default divergence theorem will give you flux for outward normal. Are you now talking about the outward normal for semi-disks at $y = 0$ and at $z = 0$?

Comment: Take semi-disk at $y=0$ for example. The disk is in the plane $y=0$. What would be the direction of the vector normal to it and outward? It is in $y$ direction, correct? Now if you take $(0, 1, 0)$ that is inward for the given spherical surface and so you choose $(0, -1, 0)$. Similarly for the other disk.

Comment: posted the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Since the divergence is zero, we can close the surface and say

$$\iint\limits_S\cdots + \iint\limits_{y_2=0}\cdots +\iint\limits_{y_3=0}\cdots = 0 \implies \iint\limits_S \cdots= -\iint\limits_{y_2=0}\cdots-\iint\limits_{y_3=0}\cdots$$

Those two integrals are easy to compute, they are constants being integrated over half circles

$$-\iint\limits_{y_1^2+y_3^2=r^2\cap y_3\geq 0}(\cdots, 0 - e^0,\cdots)\cdot (0,-1,0)dA - \iint\limits_{y_1^2+y_2^2=r^2\cap y_2\geq 0}(\cdots, \cdots, 0 - e^0)\cdot (0,0,-1)dA $$

$$=\iint\limits_{y_1^2+y_3^2=r^2\cap y_3\geq 0}1\:dA + \iint\limits_{y_1^2+y_2^2=r^2\cap y_2\geq 0}1\:dA = \frac{\pi r^2}{2}+\frac{\pi r^2}{2} = \pi r^2$$

Comment: where does (...0-e^0,...)(0,-1,0) come from?